# draw line between marker and fixed point - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

how to draw line between marker and fixed point  - Google Maps API v3

I used that code to draw a line between 2 fixed points 
and put a marker
**using google api v3**

how can i replace the **marker position** *instead* of one of the 2 fixed points ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwID2UsBJvwVKEMx_U53brmIC8EOLsBFo&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>


function initialize()
{

var x=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);


var mapProp = {
  center:x,
  zoom:4,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


 google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousemove", function(pt) { 
      document.getElementById("latlgn").innerHTML = pt.latLng; 
    });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: true,
  position: x,
  map: map,
  title: "Your location"
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});

var lat = "80";
var lng = "80"; 
var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var london=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

var myTrip=[stavanger,london];
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:myTrip,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.9,
  strokeWeight:2
  });

flightPath.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}







</script>
</head>
 <div id="latlong">
    <p>Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" ></p>
    <p>Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="lngbox" name="lng" ></p>
  </div>
<body onLoad="initialize()">

<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<div id="latlgn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the  `myTrip`-variable to

```
[stavanger,marker.getPosition()]
```

This will initially draw a line between stavanger and the markers position.

To keep the line updated when the marker has been moved, use the setPath-method of the PolyLine(flightPath) inside the callback of marker.dragend

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
    flightPath.setPath([flightPath.getPath().getAt(0),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(this.getPosition().lat(),
                                               this.getPosition().lng())]);
});
```

---

As requested, modifications to set an end of the line to the center:

```
var myTrip=[stavanger,map.getCenter()];

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function (event) {
    flightPath.setPath([flightPath.getPath().getAt(0),this.getCenter()])
});
```

Comment: thanks ...... can i link it with the center of the screen instead of the marker ??

Comment: yes, there is a method getCenter() for the map and also an event center_changed(also for the map), you only need to set the variable point of the PolyLine to `map.getCenter()`

Comment: could u please send me the modified  code for this  ? or explain it more?

Comment: thanks  please could u please check that question .. it is related to that problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557473/move-marker-to-new-position-using-form-google-api-v3