# How to draw a path as a straight line in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `polyline` to draw a path on a map using google maps v3 api. 
This is my code :

```
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: path,
          strokeColor: color,
          strokeOpacity: 10,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          editable: true              
        });
polyline.setMap(map);
```

This is a partial outcome

[image]

I'm trying to draw this path without the circles on it - I want just a regular straight line. 
If it's possible, I would like to control it's thickness.

**EDIT :** 
It's the `editable : true` that makes the line appear with circles.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554565/draw-line-between-marker-and-fixed-point-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Thanks @Spancer but i was hoping for a solution using the `polyline`. The question if referring to lines between two fixed points - ploting an entire path this way seems like the wrong way. I thought maybe there is a way to set a blank icon or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't straight what is given in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple), as well?

Still, Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v5ye/) for you to play with.

```
var mapOptions = { zoom: 2, center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 60) };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var path = [
new google.maps.LatLng(10,20),
new google.maps.LatLng(0,40),
new google.maps.LatLng(50,60)];
var pathOptions = { path: path, strokeColor: "red", strokeWeight: 2 }
var myPath = new google.maps.Polyline(pathOptions);
myPath.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Hey @loxxy - Thanks for the replay but the your code is similar to mine. I'm trying to draw a line without the circle icons for each point in the path. notice the picture in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: @haki I noticed. But you didn't share the complete code. You are probably adding markers...

Comment: The example I posted is without markers. the output i'm getting is for the exact same code you posted. I think that the API is just marking every point in the path with a circle. I looked into changing the icon but when I couldn't find any "ICON.NONE" constant I decided to reach out for the experts here ...

Comment: Ohh well. glad you figured out. :)